# unable to install nokogiri in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, nokogiri

I am trying to setup rails env on my new ubuntu machine. But I am facing trouble while install nokogiri gem.. I have installed libxslt and libxml2 libs thourgh rvm pkg command as well as using apt-get. I thought it is showing me libxslt is missing error.

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /home/hacker5/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby extconf.rb --with-xslt-include=/usr/include/libxslt
checking for libxml/parser.h... yes
checking for libxslt/xslt.h... yes
checking for libexslt/exslt.h... yes
checking for iconv_open() in iconv.h... no
checking for iconv_open() in -liconv... yes
checking for xmlParseDoc() in -lxml2... yes
checking for xsltParseStylesheetDoc() in -lxslt... no
-----
libxslt is missing.  please visit http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html for help with installing dependencies.
-----
```

**EDIT**

I am using rvm setup and ruby 1.9.3

Comment: possible duplicate of [error installing nokogiri 1.5.0 with rails 3.1.0 and ubuntu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8003523/error-installing-nokogiri-1-5-0-with-rails-3-1-0-and-ubuntu)

Answer (score 24):

Try this:

```
# nokogiri requirements
sudo apt-get install libxslt-dev libxml2-dev
gem install nokogiri
```

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libxslt-dev libxml2-dev` is sufficient for Ruby 1.9.3.

Comment: The OP clearly stated his ruby version. Installing ruby packages when he is already using rvm is of no real help.

Comment: Thanks. For me helped also: `sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev`

Answer (score 10):

For Ruby 1.9.3 and 2.0, libxslt-dev and libxml2-dev are required.

`sudo apt-get install libxslt-dev libxml2-dev`

Comment: Yes , this ran like a champ. You run this if you already have RUBY installed . and it worked.

Answer (score 9):

this is what worked for me:

1. install nokogiri's dependencies

   `sudo apt-get install libxslt-dev libxml2-dev`
2. make sure nokogiri uses the system libraries

   `export NOKOGIRI_USE_SYSTEM_LIBRARIES=1`
3. install nokogiri with the --verbose option, to get a better understanding of any problems

   `gem install --verbose nokogiri`

Comment: `gem install --verbose nokogiri` was exactly what I needed. Error: "virtual memory exhausted: Cannot allocate memory" - _sigh_

Answer (score 6):

Since I stumbled upon this, here's what I did to resolve:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1-dev
```

Answer (score 5):

On 14.0.4, using RVM, you need:

```
sudo apt-get install -y libgmp-dev
```

Comment: *This is the solution to the latest error* **Ubuntu** `14.04.4 LTS` **Ruby** `2.3.0`

Answer (score 2):

Install ruby via `rvm` and then install below libs:

```
sudo apt-get install libxslt-dev libxml2-dev
```

now try to install gem without sudo:

```
gem install nokogiri
```

Answer (score 2):

apt-get install libxslt-dev libxml2-dev -y && export NOKOGIRI_USE_SYSTEM_LIBRARIES=1 && gem install --verbose nokogiri

Answer (score 1):

for Centos / Redhat, try this:

`sudo yum install libxslt-devel libxml2-devel`