# Trying to install knife-ec2

Tags: chef-infra, knife

my chef-client version is 11.10.0
trying to install knife-ec2

```
gem install knife-ec2
```

`ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied - /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.6.1/.autotest`

i tried with other command:

```
sudo /opt/chef/embedded/bin/gem install knife-ec2
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
```

ERROR:  Error installing knife-ec2:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
     /opt/chef/embedded/bin/ruby extconf.rb
Extracting libxml2-2.8.0.tar.gz into tmp/x86_64-linux-gnu/ports/libxml2/2.8.0... OK
Running 'configure' for libxml2 2.8.0... OK
Running 'compile' for libxml2 2.8.0... ERROR, review 'tmp/x86_64-linux-gnu/ports/libxml2/2.8.0/compile                                                                  .log' to see what happened.
*** extconf.rb failed ***
```

Comment: You need to install the libxml binding. Please see [Installing Nokogiri on Ubuntu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11663499/unable-to-install-nokogiri-in-ubuntu-12-04)

Answer (score 0):

This error message tells what you missed:

```
Running 'compile' for libxml2 2.8.0... ERROR, review 'tmp/x86_64-linux-gnu/ports/libxml2/2.8.0/compile                                                                  .log' to see what happened.
*** extconf.rb failed ***
```

It tries to compile libxml2 but fails. Usually you need development library that contains header files to compile those dependencies.

Solution:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev
```

Comment: libxslt-dev is also probably missing:  `sudo apt-get install libxslt-dev libxml2-dev` and on RHEL systems:  `sudo yum install libxslt-devel libxsml2-devel`