# Error Installing Nokogiri in Linux Mint

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I've been trying for a while now to install nokogiri-1.5.0.beta.2 and I keep running into an error. It's been documented elsewhere but none of the solutions work.

```
sudo gem install nokogiri -v '1.5.0.beta.2'
```

It outputs

```
....
make
compiling xml_reader.c
compiling xml_attr.c
compiling xml_entity_reference.c
compiling xml_element_decl.c
compiling xml_xpath_context.c
xml_xpath_context.c: In function ‘xpath_generic_exception_handler’:
xml_xpath_context.c:154:3: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make: *** [xml_xpath_context.o] Error 1    make
compiling xml_reader.c
compiling xml_attr.c
compiling xml_entity_reference.c
compiling xml_element_decl.c
compiling xml_xpath_context.c
xml_xpath_context.c: In function ‘xpath_generic_exception_handler’:
xml_xpath_context.c:154:3: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make: *** [xml_xpath_context.o] Error 1
```

It's been documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13969716/nokogiri-native-extension-failing-to-build-not-libxml2-or-libxslt-missing-issue) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13085404/installing-nokogiri-v-1-5-0-gem-in-ubuntu-12-10), but no solutions work, anyone have any suggestions? I'd prefer not just updating to a newer version because I'm trying to get bundle install on someone else's work to function.

Comment: You're using a beta version, expect errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wasn't able to resolve this problem but was able to bypass it by both updating ruby and/or installing a newer version  of Nokogiri

```
gem install nokogiri
```