# Rails : bundle install nokogiri fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundle, nokogiri

When I run > bundle install

```
`An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.6.2.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.2.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Ok, so I run  > sudo gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.2.1'

I have this :

```
    Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.2.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.2.1/ext/nokogiri/gem_make.out
```

When I run the command : rails g controller...

```
Could not find gem 'rspec-rails (= 2.13.1) ruby' in the gems available on this machine.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

Please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible duplicates:

- Mac OS X: [Error to install Nokogiri on OSX 10.9 Maverick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19643153/error-to-install-nokogiri-on-osx-10-9-maverick)
- Ubuntu: [Error installing Nokogiri 1.5.0 with rails 3.1.0 and ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8003523/error-installing-nokogiri-1-5-0-with-rails-3-1-0-and-ubuntu)

The problem is probably that you have to natively install libxml and libxslt, which Nokogiri relies on.

If you run `gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.2.1' | grep libxml`, does anything show up?

Comment: Increase Graham Kaemmer answer, other libs that nokogiri need in ubuntu they are listed here
http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html#ubuntu___debian