# Can't install Nokogiri 1.4.3 gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rvm, nokogiri

Can't install nokogiri 1.4.3 gem. Nokogiri 1.6.6.2 installs without a problem. Using latest RVM on Ubuntu.

```
pm@sniegas:~$ gem install nokogiri -v '1.4.3'
Fetching: nokogiri-1.4.3.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /home/pm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20150519-7580-2yzgsg.rb extconf.rb
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/home/pm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
extconf.rb:10:in `<main>': uninitialized constant Config (NameError)

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/pm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/nokogiri-1.4.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/pm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0/nokogiri-1.4.3/gem_make.out
```

Where should I start to look for a solution?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8003523/error-installing-nokogiri-1-5-0-with-rails-3-1-0-and-ubuntu try with the solution proposed

Comment: All required libraries are installed.

Comment: Same error here trying to install `1.4.7` with `ruby 2.2.0p0 (2014-12-25 revision 49005) [x86_64-darwin13]` on OS X 10.9.5 using chruby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get `1.4.7` to install by doing (close to) the following:

```
git clone git@github.com:sparklemotion/nokogiri.git
cd nokogiri
gem install rake-compiler hoe racc rexical
git checkout v1.4.7 # 1.4.3 in your case
# edit ./ext/nokogiri/extconf.rb and replace `Config` with `RbConfig`
rake install_deps
rake install_gem
```

Hopefully I didn't forget a step.

**Edit:** Scratch that, the installed gem doesn't work. I'm going to leave this here for now in case it helps someone.

**Edit (Jonas):** Hint for the solution is in a [bug report](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/1290). I stick with Ruby 2.1.5 and it solved this issue.

Comment: Kudos to Jonas! Spent enough hours trying to make nokogiri 1.5.0 work with ruby 2.2.1. Switched to 2.1.5 and it worked.

Comment: I am not sure for other version of rake, but on version 11.3.0 need to do rake install:deps instead of rake install_deps