# Error running Extreme Startup Sinatra web server

Tags: ruby, windows, sinatra

I'm trying to set up and run the [Extreme Startup](https://github.com/rchatley/extreme_startup/blob/master/lib/extreme_startup/web_server.rb#L28-L30) coding dojo on my Windows machine.

When I try to access the front page on http://localhost:3000, I get this error:

```
application error
Errno::ENOENT at /
No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - c:/Users/mark/Desktop/extreme_startup/lib/extreme_startup/views/leaderboard.haml
file: template.rb location: initialize line: 210
BACKTRACE
(expand)
JUMP TO: GET POST COOKIES ENV
c:/Users/mark/Desktop/extreme_startup/lib/extreme_startup/web_server.rb in block in <class:WebServer>
    set :players,    Hash.new
    set :players_threads, Hash.new
    set :scoreboard, Scoreboard.new(ENV['LENIENT'])
    set :question_factory, ENV['WARMUP'] ? WarmupQuestionFactory.new : QuestionFactory.new
    set :game_state, GameState.new

    get '/' do
      haml :leaderboard, :locals => {
          :leaderboard => LeaderBoard.new(scoreboard, players, game_state),
          :players => players  }
    end

    get '/scores' do
      LeaderBoard.new(scoreboard, players, game_state).to_json
    end
GET
No GET data.
POST
No POST data.
COOKIES
No cookie data.
Rack ENV
Variable    Value
GATEWAY_INTERFACE   
CGI/1.2
HTTP_ACCEPT 
text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING    
gzip, deflate, sdch
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE    
en-US,en;q=0.8,en-GB;q=0.6,da;q=0.4
HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL  
max-age=0
HTTP_CONNECTION 
keep-alive
HTTP_HOST   
localhost:3000
HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS  
1
HTTP_USER_AGENT 
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36
HTTP_VERSION    
HTTP/1.1
PATH_INFO   
/
QUERY_STRING    
REMOTE_ADDR 
127.0.0.1
REQUEST_METHOD  
GET
REQUEST_PATH    
/
REQUEST_URI 
/
SCRIPT_NAME 
SERVER_NAME 
localhost
SERVER_PORT 
3000
SERVER_PROTOCOL 
HTTP/1.1
SERVER_SOFTWARE 
thin 1.6.3 codename Protein Powder
async.callback  
#<Method: Thin::Connection#post_process>
async.close 
#<EventMachine::DefaultDeferrable:0x00000004497b28>
rack.errors 
#<Object:0x000000031c5608>
rack.input  
#<StringIO:0x000000041a6860>
rack.logger 
#<Rack::NullLogger:0x0000000447cd28 @app=#<Rack::Protection::FrameOptions:0x0000000447ce40 @app=#<Rack::Protection::HttpOrigin:0x0000000447cee0 @app=#<Rack::Protection::IPSpoofing:0x0000000447cf80 @app=#<Rack::Protection::JsonCsrf:0x0000000447d020 @app=#<Rack::Protection::PathTraversal:0x0000000447d0c0 @app=#<Rack::Protection::XSSHeader:0x0000000447d1d8 @app=#<ExtremeStartup::WebServer:0x00000004497a88 @default_layout=:layout, @preferred_extension=nil, @app=nil, @template_cache=#<Tilt::Cache:0x00000004497a60 @cache={}>>, @options={:reaction=>:drop_session, :logging=>true, :message=>"Forbidden", :encryptor=>Digest::SHA1, :session_key=>"rack.session", :status=>403, :allow_empty_referrer=>true, :report_key=>"protection.failed", :html_types=>["text/html", "application/xhtml"], :xss_mode=>:block, :nosniff=>true, :except=>[:session_hijacking, :remote_token]}>, @options={:reaction=>:drop_session, :logging=>true, :message=>"Forbidden", :encryptor=>Digest::SHA1, :session_key=>"rack.session", :status=>403, :allow_empty_referrer=>true, :report_key=>"protection.failed", :html_types=>["text/html", "application/xhtml"], :except=>[:session_hijacking, :remote_token]}>, @options={:reaction=>:drop_session, :logging=>true, :message=>"Forbidden", :encryptor=>Digest::SHA1, :session_key=>"rack.session", :status=>403, :allow_empty_referrer=>true, :report_key=>"protection.failed", :html_types=>["text/html", "application/xhtml"], :except=>[:session_hijacking, :remote_token]}>, @options={:reaction=>:drop_session, :logging=>true, :message=>"Forbidden", :encryptor=>Digest::SHA1, :session_key=>"rack.session", :status=>403, :allow_empty_referrer=>true, :report_key=>"protection.failed", :html_types=>["text/html", "application/xhtml"], :except=>[:session_hijacking, :remote_token]}>, @options={:reaction=>:drop_session, :logging=>true, :message=>"Forbidden", :encryptor=>Digest::SHA1, :session_key=>"rack.session", :status=>403, :allow_empty_referrer=>true, :report_key=>"protection.failed", :html_types=>["text/html", "application/xhtml"], :except=>[:session_hijacking, :remote_token]}>, @options={:reaction=>:drop_session, :logging=>true, :message=>"Forbidden", :encryptor=>Digest::SHA1, :session_key=>"rack.session", :status=>403, :allow_empty_referrer=>true, :report_key=>"protection.failed", :html_types=>["text/html", "application/xhtml"], :frame_options=>:sameorigin, :except=>[:session_hijacking, :remote_token]}>>
rack.multiprocess   
false
rack.multithread    
true
rack.request.cookie_hash    
{}
rack.request.query_hash 
{}
rack.request.query_string   
rack.run_once   
false
rack.url_scheme 
http
rack.version    
[1, 0]
sinatra.accept  
[#<Sinatra::Request::AcceptEntry:0x0000000425ace8 @entry="text/html", @type="text/html", @params={}, @q=1.0>, #<Sinatra::Request::AcceptEntry:0x0000000425ab08 @entry="application/xhtml+xml", @type="application/xhtml+xml", @params={}, @q=1.0>, #<Sinatra::Request::AcceptEntry:0x0000000425a5b8 @entry="image/webp", @type="image/webp", @params={}, @q=1.0>, #<Sinatra::Request::AcceptEntry:0x0000000425a928 @entry="application/xml;q=0.9", @type="application/xml", @params={}, @q=0.9>, #<Sinatra::Request::AcceptEntry:0x0000000425a428 @entry="*/*;q=0.8", @type="*/*", @params={}, @q=0.8>]
sinatra.error   
#<Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - c:/Users/mark/Desktop/extreme_startup/lib/extreme_startup/views/leaderboard.haml>
sinatra.route   
GET /
You're seeing this error because you have enabled the show_exceptions setting.
```

As far as I can tell, the offending line of code is on line 28, [which seems to be this](https://github.com/rchatley/extreme_startup/blob/master/lib/extreme_startup/web_server.rb#L28-L30):

```
haml :leaderboard, :locals => {
    :leaderboard => LeaderBoard.new(scoreboard, players, game_state),
    :players => players  }
```

Unfortunately, my knowledge of Ruby is almost non-existent, so nothing there looks untoward to me.

When I start the web server, it produces this output, including a single warning, that I (so far unsuccessfully) have tried to get rid of. I don't know if it's related:

```
$ ruby web_server.rb
:public is no longer used to avoid overloading Module#public, use :public_folder or :public_dir instead
        from c:/Users/mark/Desktop/extreme_startup/lib/extreme_startup/web_server.rb:20:in `<class:WebServer>'
== Sinatra (v1.4.6) has taken the stage on 3000 for development with backup from Thin
Thin web server (v1.6.3 codename Protein Powder)
Maximum connections set to 1024
Listening on localhost:3000, CTRL+C to stop
```

When I issue the request to http://localhost:3000 from Chrome, the console outputs this error message:

```
WARN: tilt autoloading 'tilt/haml' in a non thread-safe way; explicit require 'tilt/haml' suggested.
2015-08-26 15:50:41 - Errno::ENOENT - No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - c:/Users/mark/Desktop/extreme_startup/lib/extreme_startup/views/leaderboard.haml:
        c:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/tilt-2.0.1/lib/tilt/template.rb:210:in `initialize'
        c:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/tilt-2.0.1/lib/tilt/template.rb:210:in `open'
        c:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/tilt-2.0.1/lib/tilt/template.rb:210:in `read_template_file'
        c:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/tilt-2.0.1/lib/tilt/template.rb:76:in `block in initialize'
        c:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/tilt-2.0.1/lib/tilt/template.rb:77:in `call'
        c:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/tilt-2.0.1/lib/tilt/template.rb:77:in `initialize'
        c:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb:861:in `new'
        c:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb:861:in `block in compile_template'
        c:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/tilt-2.0.1/lib/tilt.rb:88:in `fetch'
        c:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb:840:in `compile_template'
        c:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb:821:in `render'
        c:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb:676:in `haml'
        c:/Users/mark/Desktop/extreme_startup/lib/extreme_startup/web_server.rb:28:in `block in <class:WebServer>'
        c:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1610:in `call'
        c:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1610:in `block in compile!'
        c:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb:974:in `[]'
        c:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb:974:in `block (3 levels) in route!'
        c:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb:993:in `route_eval'
        c:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb:974:in `block (2 levels) in route!'
        c:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1014:in `block in process_route'
        c:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1012:in `catch'
        c:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1012:in `process_route'
        c:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb:972:in `block in route!'
        c:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb:971:in `each'
        c:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb:971:in `route!'
        c:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1084:in `block in dispatch!'
        c:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1066:in `block in invoke'
        c:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1066:in `catch'
        c:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1066:in `invoke'
        c:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1081:in `dispatch!'
        c:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb:906:in `block in call!'
        c:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1066:in `block in invoke'
        c:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1066:in `catch'
        c:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1066:in `invoke'
        c:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb:906:in `call!'
        c:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb:894:in `call'
        c:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-protection-1.5.3/lib/rack/protection/xss_header.rb:18:in `call'
        c:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-protection-1.5.3/lib/rack/protection/path_traversal.rb:16:in `call'
        c:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-protection-1.5.3/lib/rack/protection/json_csrf.rb:18:in `call'
        c:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-protection-1.5.3/lib/rack/protection/base.rb:49:in `call'
        c:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-protection-1.5.3/lib/rack/protection/base.rb:49:in `call'
        c:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-protection-1.5.3/lib/rack/protection/frame_options.rb:31:in `call'
        c:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/nulllogger.rb:9:in `call'
        c:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
        c:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/show_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
        c:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb:181:in `call'
        c:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb:2021:in `call'
        c:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1486:in `block in call'
        c:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1795:in `synchronize'
        c:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1486:in `call'
        c:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/thin-1.6.3/lib/thin/connection.rb:86:in `block in pre_process'
        c:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/thin-1.6.3/lib/thin/connection.rb:84:in `catch'
        c:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/thin-1.6.3/lib/thin/connection.rb:84:in `pre_process'
        c:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.8/lib/eventmachine.rb:1062:in `call'
        c:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.8/lib/eventmachine.rb:1062:in `block in spawn_threadpool'
```

What's wrong, and what can I do to fix the issue?

I know almost nothing about Ruby, so it's probably a stupid beginner's mistake.

Comment: I guess you have checked that `c:/Users/mark/Desktop/extreme_startup/lib/extreme_startup/views/leaderboard.haml` exists?

Comment: @Sirl33tname As a matter of fact, I hadn't :$ I just [cloned the repository](https://github.com/rchatley/extreme_startup) and naively assumed that everything would work. As you may have guessed, the file isn't there. Do I need to somehow 'build' the app in order to makes this file (and others) appear? Could the issue be connected to the warning about `:public`?

Comment: I don't use git with windows but I just checked it out with git on linux and I have that file, so I guess something gone wrong in the git checkout. The warning about public folder setting, is just a warning I'm not 100% sure if it could make problems, but I'm really sure that it's not related with your problem.

Comment: @Sirl33tname If you look in [the GitHub web view, you'll see that `lib/extreme_startup` has no sub-directories](https://github.com/rchatley/extreme_startup/tree/master/lib/extreme_startup). The `leaderboard.haml` file exists in the repo, but [in `/views`](https://github.com/rchatley/extreme_startup/tree/master/views). That file is on my hard drive as well. The error message seems to hint that the web server is looking for the view files in the wrong place, or am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the application was developed a long time ago an nobody took the time to upgrade.

For example you should run it with ruby 1.9.3 which is end of live. 
But using a newer ruby version would probably work. (at least ruby-2.1.6 works for me)

But what definitely not works is to run this project with sinatra v1.4.6. 
As you can see in the source code this project was build with [v1.2.6](https://github.com/rchatley/extreme_startup/blob/master/Gemfile.lock#L57). 
Probably you have installed a newer version of sinatra for a other project.
So I would recommend that you install the gems in your project folder with:

> bundle install --binstubs --path vendor

If installed this way you can have multiple projects with the same dependency with out a problem. But now you need to prefix you commands with **bundle exec** for example `bundle exec ruby web_server.rb`.

Or if you are using rvm there is this thing called [gemsets](https://rvm.io/gemsets/basics) which does something similar.

Comment: Thank you. The problem with that command is that if I issue that, I run into [this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32224128/126014). Is there a way to get past both hurdles?

Comment: Can you replace your Gemfile.lock with this http://pastebin.com/xCBfeTkV and try again?

Comment: Thank you for your effort. It now gets past the nokogiri step, but then it fails while installing `ffi`. It's quite a massive error message there, so I almost dare not post it. I think I'll post an issue on the repo and see if the original author'd be interested in updating the code. Thank you very much for your kind efforts.

Comment: It's probably easier to setup a linux VM ;D

Comment: It probably is, if one knows how to do that - which I don't :$

Comment: Feel free to message me on Twitter or somewhere else infos are on my site

Comment: Thank you, that's very kind of you, but after all, I consider Stack Overflow a better medium for technical troubleshooting than Twitter. FWIW, I've [created an issue in the original repo](https://github.com/rchatley/extreme_startup/issues/46).