# Ubuntu 14.04 Rails missing file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, terminal

when installing Rails, everything was good but then, i write:

```
rails -v
```

and the output:

```
/home/toshiba/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- rails/cli (LoadError)
from /home/toshiba/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from /usr/bin/rails:7:in `<main>'
```

everyone know how to do it?

I used this tutorial: http://installfest.railsbridge.org/

and yes, i run:

```
gem install rails
```

I noticed that when i run install rails this thing is pop up

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/home/toshiba/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20150816-3818-sm5w21.rb extconf.rb
checking if the C compiler accepts -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c99 -Wall -Werror... yes
Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.
checking for gzdopen() in -lz... no
zlib is missing; necessary for building libxml2
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.     You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--without-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/home/toshiba/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
--help
--clean
--use-system-libraries
--enable-static
--disable-static
--with-zlib-dir
--without-zlib-dir
--with-zlib-include
--without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
--with-zlib-lib
--without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
--enable-cross-build
--disable-cross-build

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/toshiba/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/toshiba/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/gem_make.out
```

It seems bad

Comment: How are you installing it?

Comment: `bundle install` ? did you look for similar issues from other users ?

Comment: You mean `bundle install rails`? please include the way you install it in the question body, there are many ways to install Rails and `bundle install` is arguably the least used way.

Comment: i used this tutorial: http://installfest.railsbridge.org/

Comment: Double check that you actually ran `gem install rails`

Comment: yes, i run
    gem install rails

Comment: OK maybe try running `gem install rails` again, or running `gem uninstall rails` and then installing it again.

Comment: Just an observation, cli is an Ember component.

Comment: what that means @Val Asensio?

Comment: It seems like Rails cli is not related to Ember cli -- "cli" is an acronym for "command line interface."

Comment: possible duplicate of [error installing nokogiri 1.5.0 with rails 3.1.0 and ubuntu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8003523/error-installing-nokogiri-1-5-0-with-rails-3-1-0-and-ubuntu)

Comment: read the error message `zlib is missing; necessary for building libxml2`

Answer (score 17):

I've fixed this problem by

```
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev
```

Comment:  Great! Thank you so much.

Comment: On my Ubuntu 16.04 it doesn't help (same error message), even though `zlib1g-dev is already the newest version (1:1.2.8.dfsg-2ubuntu4.1)`.

Answer (score 0):

This pops up in your install process:

```
zlib is missing; necessary for building libxml2
```

I guess you need to `sudo apt-get install libxml2`.

**Edit** I got downvoted and probably the answer about installing `zlib` is (more?) correct. I wonder if installing libxml2 (or libxml2-dev) would have helped as well, there was unfortunately no comment about output of that experiment.

Comment: I got downvoted - anybody tried whether libxml2 does pull zlib with it?